# Remove date from the french style for the ConTeXt letter module

Tags: context, letters

I'm using the ConTeXt's letter module with the `french` style but I don't want the date do appear. I tried to setup an empty list of elements to display but it didn't work,

```
\setupletter
    [list={}]
```

Edit:

The following version has the date. But if I change the style to `knuth` the date disappears.

```
\usemodule[letter][style=french]

\starttext

\setupletter
  [fromname={Your Name},
   fromaddress={Street\\Town},
   fromphone={Phone}]

\setupletter
  [list={}]

\setupletter
  [subject={Subject}]

\setupletter
  [toname={Addressee},
   toaddress={Street\\Town}]

\startletter
  [opening={Dear Reader},
   closing={Sincerely,},
   signature={Signature}]


\stopletter

\stoptext
```

Comment: I think we need a full minimal example (also, are we talking Mark II or Mark IV?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Based on information from Wolfgang Schuster, author of the `letter` module.)

To remove the date you can use

```
\setupletterstyle
  [location]
  [alternative=none]
```

leading to a full minimal example

```
\usemodule[letter][style=french]

\setupletter
  [fromname={Your Name},
   fromaddress={Street\\Town},
   fromphone={Phone}]

\setupletterstyle
  [location]
  [alternative=none]

\setupletter
  [subject={Subject}]

\setupletter
  [toname={Addressee},
   toaddress={Street\\Town}]

\startletter
  [opening={Dear Reader},
   closing={Sincerely,},
   signature={Signature}]

\input knuth

\stopletter
```

(You don’t even need `\starttext` here because it’s already part of `\startletter`)

Using the `list` setting does not work because in the `french` style the `location` block is used to place the date and not the `reference` block as used in the other styles.

Wolfgang also says

> The `knuth` isn’t a solution for the problem because it’s none of the
>   official styles and I use it only for a gimmick of the module where
>   you can use the commands from the letter code in *The TeXbook*.